# Can IE AutoComplete can automatically fill form like AutoFill?

Tags: internet-explorer, autocomplete, autofill

Chrome has the auto complete feature that fills a form even if the user did not type anything.

Is there a way to make IE AutoComplete to act the same way?

Thanks.